# Balloon material cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have been working on these balloons and trying to make them look realistic, but I cant seem to figure it out. What could I do differently? (im attaching my blender file) As you can see inside my blender file I have played around with quite a lot of different node setups, but nothing has been working.
[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Try making the balloons slightly transparent. Maybe add hdri lighting so that the balloons can reflect some of the environment.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that as well! It works fairly good if you find the right HDRI. I would like to know how to do it with the other lights as well. But maybe HDRIs are the future! Now they look pretty good! I also played around adding a Principled BSDF (instead of transparant BSDF) and played around with the transmission values and roughness.